# C++ Saving 2-dimensional database into file ISSUE

Tags: c++, arrays, file, save

I'm writing a small console app (name it student evidention), which has couple of functions, i.e it allows user to export database into text file.

The problem which occurs during this process is that program actually saves only the first record of mentioned database.

```
void saveDataToFile() {             // ZAPISZ BAZĘ DANYCH DO PLIKU - ISTNIEJE PROBLEM Z OKREŚLENIEM ŚCIEŻKI ZAPISU ORAZ ZAPISYWANIEM JEDYNIE PIERWSZEGO REKORDU Z BAZY
string fileName;
ofstream fileTemp;
cout << "Podaj nazwę pliku: "; cin >> fileName;
fileTemp.open(fileName);
fileTemp << "+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+" << endl;
fileTemp << "|\tImię\t|\tNazwisko\t|\tNr PESEL\t|\t Telefon\t|\tMail\t |" << endl << "+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+" << endl;
for (row; row < 20; row++) {
    for (col; col < 5; col++) {
        if (col == 0) {
            fileTemp << "\t" << studentDb[row][col] << "\t";
        }
        else {
            fileTemp << studentDb[row][col] << "\t";
        }
    }
    fileTemp << endl;
}
fileTemp.close();
```

}

I have no idea what's wrong with that code, because the loop itself seems to be completely fine...

I'd be glad for any tips for resolving this issue.
Ignore lines written in polish - it has only some cosmetic, text-formatting functions in the program.

**EDIT.**

The way I create a new record:

```
void createNewRecord() {        // UTWÓRZ NOWY REKORD W BAZIE
string *pNewRecord;
pNewRecord = &studentDb[recordCounter][0];
cout << "Imię: "; cin >> *pNewRecord;
pNewRecord = &studentDb[recordCounter][1];
cout << "Nazwisko: "; cin >> *pNewRecord;
pNewRecord = &studentDb[recordCounter][2];
cout << "Numer PESEL: "; cin >> *pNewRecord;
pNewRecord = &studentDb[recordCounter][3];
cout << "Numer telefonu: "; cin >> *pNewRecord;
pNewRecord = &studentDb[recordCounter][4];
cout << "Adres e-mail: "; cin >> *pNewRecord;
recordCounter++;
cout << endl << "Nowy rekord został pomyślnie dodany do bazy." << endl;
cout << "Czy chcesz kontynuować? (t/n): "; cin >> response;
cout << endl;
if (response == 't' || response == 'T') {
    cout << "Kontynuujesz dodawanie do bazy." << endl << endl;
    createNewRecord();
}
else if (response == 'n' || response == 'N') {
    Sleep(1000);
    system("cls");
    void displayMenuWindow();
}
```

}

Comment: Are `row` and `col` class members? Why don't you use local variables as loop indices?

Comment: Did you step through the loop in a debugger?

Comment: Is it possible that you _do_ write all of the records, but they are all in one line because you do not insert line breaks after each record?

Comment: col & row are globally defined variables, which I use in multiple nested array-operating loops within the program. Debugger returns no visible issues or errors.

Comment: I think using global loop indices is asking for trouble.

Comment: after each use I set them back to 0.

Comment: What if you have nested loops or multithreading? I think it is a high risk with nothing to gain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the 'row' and 'col' variables to zero in the initializer portion of the 'for' loops. And make them local variables too (declare them as "int row=0").

Comment: Yes, it worked! Thank you very much and I withdraw all my previous words about these damn variables.